# slide change on hover with nextgen scrollgallery

Tags: jquery, plugin-nextgen-gallery, slideshow

My jquery skill is pretty bad, so I can not seem to achieve this. I have a nextgen gallery album that has a scroll gallery showing the images in a slideshow. I want to change the slides on hover rather than on click. I know it is pretty simple, but I have no idea how to actually do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I am providing intiates the click event when mouse enters the thumbnail (with a delay to avoid passing mouse events).

```
jQuery('.scrollgallery .thumbarea img').hover(function(e){
  this.ScrollGalleryHover = setTimeout('initiateClick("'+jQuery(this).attr('src')+'");',500);
},function(e) {
  clearTimeout(this.ScrollGalleryHover);
});

function initiateClick(src) {
  jQuery('.scrollgallery .thumbarea img[src="'+src+'"]').click();
}
```